# Prove $\lim_{r\rightarrow +\infty} \int_{B(0,r)} {\frac{1}{1+x^2+|y|}}dx dy=+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

The integral esiste because the integrand function is continuous over a compact set.
For simmetry I compute the integral over a quarter of a circle.

My idea is to increase the integrand function with something that is not integrable

Can I say $\int_{B(0,r)} f >\int_{|x|+|y|<r} f$?

Answer (score 0):

Hints: show that for any $M \in (0,\infty)$ the given integral exceeds $\int_{-M} ^{M}\int_{-M} ^{M} \frac1 {1+x^{2}+|y|} dydx$ for $r$ sufficiently large and the show that $\int_{-M} ^{M}\frac1 {1+x^{2}+|y|} dy \to \infty$ as $M \to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Make integral on $B(0,r)$ is the same that make it  in $|x|+|y|<r$?